# C++ Text based game

Tags: c++

I am currently making a small console based text game in C++ with visual studio 2010.
I have encounted the problem of; when I get my  name entered and difficulty selected I go to make the introductory text and I enter :

```
cout <<"Welcome "<<userName<<"... You are a lone: "<<pickRace<<" Your journey will be a "<<difficulty<<" one.";
```

And I want it to show up as : Welcome Blake... you are a lone Human/Orc your journey will be a easy/medium/hard one.

But I comes up as Welcome Blake... you are a lone 1/2 your jouney will be a 1/2/3 one.

this is a problem I think due to my switch's could anyone tell me how I need to rewrite them to get it appear with the name instead of numbers?

original code :

```
cout <<"Please pick your race: \n";
cout <<"1 - Human\n";
cout <<"2 - Orc\n";
int pickRace;
cout <<"Pick your race: ";
cin >>pickRace;

switch (pickRace)
{
case 1:
    cout <<"You picked the Human race.\n";
    break;
case 2:
    cout <<"You Picked the Orc race\n";
    break;
default:
    cout <<"Error - Invalid imput; only 1 or 2 allowed.\n";
}


int difficulty;
cout <<"\nPick your level diffuculty: \n";
cout <<"1 - Easy\n";
cout <<"1 - Medium\n";
cout <<"3 - Hard\n";

cout <<"Pick your level difficulty: ";
cin >>difficulty;

switch (difficulty)
{
case 1:
    cout <<"You picked Easy.\n\n";
    break;
case 2:
    cout <<"You picked Medium.\n\n";
    break;
case 3:
    cout <<"You picked Hard.\n\n";
    break;
default:
    cout <<"Error - Invalid imut; only 1,2 or 3 allowed.\n";
}
```

Comment: Code. We need to see your code.

Comment: Can't tell you how to rewrite something when we haven't seen original writing.  Show us the code where you declare and set values to `pickRace` and `difficulty`.

Comment: Guess you want us to second guess the homework problem?

Comment: @jrok No, you don't understand: This is the game, it already started. OP: I hit the Orc with a friend declaration!

Comment: Are you storing `pickRace` and `difficulty` as integers?

Comment: Are you writing a text game to learn C++, or are you learning C++ to write a text game? In former case, read a good book, in the latter case, don't use C++ (I'd suggest Python).

Comment: I suggest you create a table to convert from ID numbers to text strings.  Use the lookup table when printing or inputting.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing `pickRace` and `difficulty` as `integers`. Try doing something like:

```
int pickRace;
string raceText;    //we will store the race type using this
cout <<"Pick your race: ";
cin >>pickRace;

switch (pickRace)
{
    case 1:
        cout <<"You picked the Human race.\n";
        raceText = "Human";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout <<"You Picked the Orc race\n";
        raceText = "Orc";
        break;
    default:
        cout <<"Error - Invalid imput; only 1 or 2 allowed.\n";
}
```

**Note** the `raceText` string variable.

Repeat this for difficulty.

Then use raceText and difficultyText to print your message:

```
out <<"Welcome "<<userName<<"... You are a lone: "<<raceText<<" Your journey will be a "<<difficultyText<<" one.";
```

Comment: either use std::string or use character array.

Comment: everything seems to have worked fine here except on the last line  cout <<"Welcome "<<userName<<"... You are a lone: "<<raceText<<" Your journey will be a "<<difficultyText<<" one.";   at the "<< on racetext it says: "no operator "<<" Matches these operands...

Comment: You may have to prefix string with `std::` as Shubendra mentioned ( So std::string raceText; ). Or declare the string the same way you declared `userName`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `enum`s and overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` for them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

enum difficulty { EASY = 1, MEDIUM = 2, HARD = 3 };

std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, difficulty& d )
{
     int i;
     is >> i;
     assert( i > 0 && i < 4 ); // TODO: Use real error handling, throw an exception
     d = difficulty( i );
     return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, difficulty d )
{
    switch( d ) {
    case EASY: return os << "easy";
    case MEDIUM: return os << "medium";
    case HARD: return os << "hard";
    }
    return os << "unknown[" << (int)d << "]";
}

int main()
{
    difficulty d;
    std::cout << "Pick difficulty: 1-easy, 2-medium, 3-hard: ";
    std::cin >> d;
    std::cout << "You picked difficulty: " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect it to print `string` when you are storing choices as `int`s...

You can use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
#include <map>


std::map<int, std::string> difficulty;

difficulty[1] = "easy";
difficulty[2] = "medium";
difficulty[3] = "hard";

int choice_difficulty;
std::cin>>choice_difficulty;

/*Check if user entered correct number*/
std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it = difficulty.find(choice_difficulty);
if(it == difficulty.end())
    std::cout << "wrong choice";

cout <<"Welcome "<<userName<<" Your journey will be a "<<difficulty[choice_difficulty];
```

Comment: One issue with your suggestion is that the `std::map` has to be loaded during initialization of the program.  A lookup table may be a better solution since it is constant.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use lookup tables to convert between `enum`s or numeric IDentifiers (IDs) and the text they represent.

For example:

```
struct Race_Text_Entry
{
    const char *  text;
    unsigned int  id;
};

static const Race_Text_Entry race_name_table[] =
{
  {"Unknown", 0},
  {"Human",   ID_HUMAN_RACE},
  {"Orc",     ID_ORC_RACE},
  {"Elf",     ID_ELF_RACE},
};
static const unsigned int NUM_RACE_ENTRIES =
    sizeof(race_name_table) / sizeof(race_name_table[0]);

std::string Race_ID_To_Text(unsigned int id)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    std::string race_name = "Race unknown";
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_RACE_ENTRIES; ++i)
    {
       if (race_name_table[i].id == id)
       {
           race_name = race_name_table.text;
           break;
       }
    }
    return race_name;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "My race: " << Race_ID_To_Text(ID_RACE_HUMAN) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

A nice advantage to the constant lookup table as an array, is that it can be stored in the read-only data section of the program and loaded with the constant data.  The initialization time is negligible compared with creating a `std::map` variable during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

pickRace and difficulty are Integers. You're printing integers instead of the actual difficulty. You need to somehow logically represent the difficulty (and pickRace)